# Rewrite a query to Avoid Subqueries

Tags: sql-server

I need to rewrite below query avoiding the sub query. How should i do it....There are two subqueries in the below query

```
select  
  cc1.claimid as claimid,
  cc1.createdate as createdate,
  cc1.condcode as condition_cd1,
  cc2.condcode as condition_cd2,
  cc3.condcode as condition_cd3

from claimcond cc1 (nolock)
left outer join claimcond cc2 (nolock) on 
cc1.claimid = cc2.claimid 
and cc2.condcode = (select min(condcode) from claimcond cc (nolock) where cc1.claimid = cc.claimid)
and cc1.condcode <> cc2.condcode

left outer join claimcond cc3 (nolock) on 
cc1.claimid = cc3.claimid 
and cc3.condcode in (select min(condcode) from claimcond cc (nolock) where cc1.claimid = cc.claimid 
and ((cc.condcode > cc2.condcode)))
and cc1.condcode <> cc3.condcode

ORDER BY cc1.claimid, cc1.condcode DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Exists:

```
select  
  cc1.claimid as claimid,
  cc1.createdate as createdate,
  cc1.condcode as condition_cd1,
  cc2.condcode as condition_cd2,
  cc3.condcode as condition_cd3

from claimcond cc1 (nolock)
left outer join claimcond cc2 (nolock) on 
cc1.claimid = cc2.claimid 
and cc1.condcode <> cc2.condcode

left outer join claimcond cc3 (nolock) on 
cc1.claimid = cc3.claimid 

and ((cc.condcode > cc2.condcode)))
and cc1.condcode <> cc3.condcode
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT '1'
    FROM claimcond cc (nolock)
    WHERE cc1.claimid = cc.claimid and -- Maybe OR 
          cc2.claimID = cc.claimid )

ORDER BY cc1.claimid, cc1.condcode DESC
```

Comment: Getting error.... Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
The multi-part identifier "cc.condcode" could not be bound.

Comment: It's this line: and ((cc.condcode > cc2.condcode)))

Answer (score 0):

You should see how this performs:

```
DECLARE @MinCondCode TABLE (
    claimid INT,                --datatype correct?
    MinCode1 VARCHAR(20) NULL,  --datatype correct?
    MinCode2 VARCHAR(20) NULL   --datatype correct?
)

INSERT INTO @MinCondCode (claimid,MinCode1)
    select claimid,min(condcode)
    from claimcond cc (nolock)
    group by claimid

UPDATE MinCondCode
SET MinCode2=(
    select min(condcode)
    from claimcond cc (nolock)
    WHERE cc.condcode > MinCondCode.MinCode1
    AND MinCondCode.claimid = cc.claimid 
)

select  
  cc1.claimid as claimid,
  cc1.createdate as createdate,
  cc1.condcode as condition_cd1,
  cc2.condcode as condition_cd2,
  cc3.condcode as condition_cd3
from claimcond cc1 (nolock)
INNER JOIN @MinCondCode mn on mn.claimid=cc1.claimid
left outer join claimcond cc2 (nolock) on cc1.claimid = cc2.claimid 
    and cc2.condcode = mn.MinCode1
    and cc1.condcode <> cc2.condcode
left outer join claimcond cc3 (nolock) on cc1.claimid = cc3.claimid 
    and cc3.condcode = mn.MinCode2
    and cc1.condcode <> cc3.condcode
ORDER BY cc1.claimid, cc1.condcode DESC
```

Comment: Getting error, Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Column 'claimcond.claimid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.